# Whitelist URL in chrome custom tabs android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

What is the best way/best practice to implement URL whitelisting in  chrome custom tabs on android ?

It was pretty easy to do in Web view implementations on android , but how does CCT handle this.

Is it really possible at all in android?

Answer (score 0):

Once a chrome custom tab is running, it runs in a separate process (unlike web views). Currently there is no way to be able to capture what url is being visited on the custom tab right now (besides the url with which you start the custom tab with).

The only level of url whitelisting that can be done is to make sure only a whitelisted url can be opened while instantiating the custom tab, but once its running the user can navigate to any url within the custom tab and there is no way to get a handle on that.

Comment: Can you suggest or share links how this is possible "url whitelisting that can be done is to make sure only a whitelisted url can be opened while instantiating the custom tab"